# Doctrine2 QB – how to select entities where OnetoOne entity doesn't exists

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, query-builder

I have two entities:

```
class User extends BaseEntity {

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Profile", mappedBy="user", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     * @var Profile
     */
    protected $profile;
}

class Profile extends BaseEntity {

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="profile", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE")
     * @var User
     */
    protected $user;
}
```

What I'm trying to do is to SELECT only `users` who don't have any profile (so there's no `profile` row with `user_id=:user_id` in `profiles` table). However, I have no idea how to make my QueryBuilder.

First, I tried something simple like

```
//u as user
$query = $this->er->createQueryBuilder('u');
$query
    ->join('u.profile', 'p')
    ->where('u.profile = 1');
```

But that returns `A single-valued association path expression to an inverse side is not supported in DQL queries. Use an explicit join instead.` so I suppose there's something wrong with my relationship? I tried to switch `join()` for `leftJoin()` but it didn't help either...

So what's up with this error and how to make proper condition with `where()` to tell Doctrine I want only users where there's no profile?

Answer (score 3):

Here is how I was able to do it. Basically I had Domain & Hosting entities and I wanted to select Domains that had no Hosting attached to them in a one to one relationship.

```
$er->createQueryBuilder('d')
                    ->leftJoin('d.hosting', 'h')
                    ->where('h.id is NULL');
```

Credits for this solution goes to this [Answer](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.php.doctrine.user/3841)

Hope it works for you since our situations are almost identical.

Answer (score 1):

Just check for `null` as value of `profile`

```
//u as user
$query = $this->er->createQueryBuilder('u');
$query
    ->where('u.profile is NULL');
```

Comment: Yea, I found that on this forum but wasn't able to check this condition because it keeps throwing me `Doctrine\ORM\Query\QueryException: A single-valued association path expression to an inverse side is not supported in DQL queries. Use an explicit join instead.`. But I suppose that condition is all right. Thank you. Any Idea how to solve that exception?

Comment: it doesn't work because it throws the error as stated above.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use repositories, example for **UserRepository**:

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('u');
$e  = $qb->expr();
$qb->leftJoin('u.profile', 'p')
    ->where($e->isNull('p.id'))
```

Raw query will look like this:

```
SELECT * FROM users AS u LEFT JOIN u.profile AS p WHERE p.id IS NULL;
```